# Functions in a finite set

Tags: functions, algorithms

Can anyone help me with this question? I have no idea where to begin how to find this algorithm.

Let $f(s)$ be a function from a finite set $S$ into itself. Define for all $s\in S$, $f(s) = s$ and $f^{(n)}(s) = f\left(f^{(n-1)}(s)\right)$ for $n>0$. Give an efficient algorithm to identify for each $x$ the smallest $n$ and $k$ such that $f^{(n)}(x) = f^{(n+k)}(x)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! this site uses latex to format math notations, please use it in your posts. I have edited your post, please inform that the edit is correct.

Comment: You mean $f^{(0)}(s) = s$, after "Define for all $s\in S$...$", right ?

Comment: Do you want an algorithm that for a given $x$ finds the smallest such $n$, or do you want one that in effect produces a table giving the smallest such $n$ for each element of $S$?

Comment: yea i mean f^(0)(s) = s
(sorry i don't know how to put it in LaTex)

Comment: the algorithm should find a given x for the smallest n

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

You are asked to find , for each $x$, the lowest numbers $n$ and $k$ such that $f^{(n)}(x) = f^{(n+k)}(x)$.

You are looking for an algorithm that will find the first "cycle" of length $k$.

Since $f$ maps from $S$ to $S$, $f^{(n)} (x) \in S$, for all n. Fix any $x$. If we repeatedly apply $f$ to $x$ (as in $f(x), f(f(x)), f(f(f(x))), \ldots ,f^{(k)}(x))$, one of these $f^{(i)}(x)$, where $0\leq i \leq k$, is equal to an element $f^{(j)}(x)$, where $0 \leq j \leq i \leq n$, that we have already mapped to, since $S$ is finite. You need to find an efficient algorithm to find these indices $i$ and $j$.

Comment: thank you for clearing this up! Now finding that algorithm is what I have no idea how to do haha

Comment: also S is a finite set not infinite!

Comment: I believe that is what I said.